# Javascript + PHP + mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, architecture

I am a beginner doing a single player browser game as a hobby mostly to learn javascript + php + mySQL.

For some reason I want front end to be done exclusively with javascript (drawing levels, inventory, etc.) Broadly speaking, I will be heavily manipulating DOM using jQuery.

In the backend there is a mySQL database. In the middle there is PHP which I see serving two purposes: i) speak to DB , ii) validate logic and respond to requests coming from front end (i.e javascript).

For example, intended flow is:

1. user wants to open a door and interacts  with a relevant element in the browser - clicks on it.
2. Action requires validation.  AJAX call to PHP saying “user wants to open the door”.
3. PHP check with DB to see if the user has got a key in inventory, does some backend logic checks to ensure that the right door can be opened and responds, e.g. with “1” , meaning that the user has got the right key and action is "valid". PHP could also tag this door's status in DB as "unlocked" which means that player does not need a key to pass through it again. Key is removed from inventory record in DB.
4. Javascript receives PHP response and renders inventory and location anew (e.g. image of a key is now missing in player’s inventory and the door is drawn differently), could possibly start a dialog on screen and perform other DOM manipulations.

I would really appreciate some advice on how to handle the “session part” of such setup. Obviously, if there is a number of players playing the game at the same time, PHP needs to look up records in DB relevant for the player, which would be normally used by userid attribute in $_SESSION.

I understand that javascript can only operate with cookies and not with sessions. I would think that a cookie could be generated with some random ID and this random ID would be written to DB. Then, when AJAX posts to PHP, this ID would be included into the post and used to look up things in DB. Then PHP would respond and front end would be changed accordingly to the player affected but not for everyone else. Am I on the right track?

Would be most happy to have some small piece of code which could illustrate this or another solution.

On another note, would such setup be OK in terms of performance or should I consider fully using .php and leave JS do to some minor job (e..g initial validation of forms before posting, etc.)?

Comment: When you're issued a session in PHP it saves session data on the server referenced with a session ID. This ID is in turn sent to the clients browser as a PHPSESSID cookie. So yes using javascript / ajax you can use sessions (as the cookie will be utilized)

Comment: @JimL Suppose that .php never opened in browser, user only operates with .html page. So, a session is not started. .php is purely on server to speak to DB and do some validation, not to serve content. How do handle it in this case?

Comment: easiest solution is to have the user access a php file, start the session and output the HTML